# git alias with ...&& git push command won't push

Tags: git, git-alias

I have an alias of:

`$HOME/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
        ...
        cmall       = !git add -A && git commit -m $1 && git push
```

which looks correct from what I've read, but the `git push` part isn't working:

```
(repo)me:~/work_projects/repo$ git cmall "test"
On branch ckc/blah
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/ckc/blah' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I go into shell and `git push`, it works just fine. How do you push in git alias?

Comment: put the whole alias inside quotes? `!"git add -A && git commit -m $1 && git push"`

Comment: FYI: "git commit -a" do the add for you.

Comment: I think gaskoin was all I needed, I forgot bout that one

Comment: @hjpotter92 shouldn't the `!` be inside?